# Perl6: .sort() doesn't use overridden cmp

Tags: raku

According to [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort), `sort` compares using `infix:<cmp>`.

But:

```
class Point
{
    has Int $.x;
    has Int $.y;
    method Str { "($!x,$!y)" }
    method gist { self.Str }
}
multi sub infix:<cmp>(Point $a, Point $b) { $a.y cmp $b.y || $a.x cmp $b.x }

my @p = Point.new(:3x, :2y), Point.new(:2x, :4y), Point.new(:1x, :1y);
say @p.sort;
```

gives output:

```
((1,1) (2,4) (3,2))
```

When I use:

```
say @p.sort(&infix:<cmp>);
```

it *does* give the proper output:

```
((1,1) (3,2) (2,4))
```

Is this a bug, a feature, or a flaw in the documentation?
And is there a way to make `.sort()` on a list of a `Point`s use a custom sort order without specifying a routine?

Comment: If I insert a `say` in that cmp method, it does not get called at all. It must be a matter of getting the signature right. Let me see if I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's a case of Broken By Design. Consider the following snippet:

```
my $a = Point.new(:3x, :2y);
my $b = Point.new(:2x, :4y);

say &infix:<cmp>.WHICH;
say $a cmp $b;

{
    multi sub infix:<cmp>(Point $a, Point $b) { $a.y cmp $b.y || $a.x cmp $b.x }
    say &infix:<cmp>.WHICH;
    say $a cmp $b;
}

say &infix:<cmp>.WHICH;
say $a cmp $b;
```

The definition of the new multi candidate will generate a new proto sub that is only visible lexically. As the `sort` method is defined in the setting (conceptionally, an enclosing scope), it won't see your new multi candidate.

It might be possible to make `sort` look up `&infix:<cmp>` dynamically instead of lexically, though I suspect such a change would have to wait for 6.e even if we decided that's something we want to do, which isn't a given.

As a workaround, you could do something like

```
constant CMP = &infix:<cmp>;
multi sub infix:<cmp>(Point $a, Point $b) { ... }
BEGIN CMP.wrap(&infix:<cmp>);
```

for now, though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it (messing with global state considered harmful, and all that jazz)...

Comment: Thanks, that is clear but unfortunate.  It might be nice if the documentation for `sort` would warn about this.

Answer (score 3):

The `cmp` that is being used is the cmp that is in lexical scope within `sort`, not the one you have defined. If you change a few lines to:

```perl6
multi sub infix:<cmp>(Point $a, Point $b) { 
  say "Hey $a $b";
  $a.y cmp $b.y || $a.x cmp $b.x 
}
my @p = Point.new(:3x, :2y), Point.new(:2x, :4y), Point.new(:1x, :1y);
say @p.sort( { $^b cmp $^a } );
```

Since the `cmp` that is being used is the one that is in actual lexical scope, it gets called correctly printing:

`Hey (2,4) (3,2)
Hey (1,1) (2,4)
Hey (1,1) (3,2)
((2,4) (3,2) (1,1))`

As was required.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear.  `@p.sort({ $^a cmp $^b })` doesn't really add anything over `@p.sort(&infix:<cmp>)` though.

Comment: Well, the order of $a and $b was reversed in @jjmerelo's answer.  Not sure that was intended.  If it wasn't then, you could also use `&[cmp]` as a shortcut for `&infix:<cmp>`.  Either of which will do a Schwartzian transform under the hood.  Which shows up in this example as only 2 Hey's instead of 3.

Comment: Thanks @Elizabeth, `&[cmp]` is a little bit nicer.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen, I'm not sure about the Schwartzian transform, though.  That works with a one-argument function, not a comparison function, right?  Note that `@p.sort({ $^a cmp $^b })` also says only two Hey's, in contrast with `@p.sort({ $^b cmp $^a })`'s 3 Hey's...

Comment: @mscha: you're right: it looks at the cardinality of the Callable.  Duh.  :-)